# Use of : HasMany in Laravel model snippet

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I want to know what is this `: hasMany` in function?

I am using [Laravel Snippets](https://github.com/onecentlin/laravel5-snippets-vscode), and it auto inserts this snippet for a relationship,
When running this relationship, it throws error,

**message: "Return value of App\Models\Customers::invoices() must be an instance of App\Models\SalesInvoices, instance of Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany returned"**

```
    /**
     * Get all of the Invoices for the Customers
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany
     */
    public function invoices(): HasMany
    {
        return $this->hasMany(SalesInvoices::class, 'customer_id', 'customer_id');
    }
```

if I removed `: HasMany`, then works fine, so what is the use of this in the snippet?

Comment: What code is throwing that error?

Comment: @apokryfos, its give above,

Comment: Ok so to clarify this is an error in the IDE not an error thrown when you actually run any code ?

Comment: @apokryfos, when it runs code it shows this error.

Comment: the return type is unnecessary anyway, why do you need to specify return type?

Comment: What you shared is just a function. How are you calling that function?

Comment: @Psycho, I don't want to use that, I just asked why snippet give than : hasMany return by default.

Comment: yes, please share how you are calling the function, then we may try to find why the error occurs